# L'usage du pronom "en" dans "il n'en est pas question" et "il y en a d'autres"

Tags: pronoms, en

Quoique je (pense que je) comprends le pronom **en**, je suis toujours troublé par certains cas que je vois.

Je sais que l'on peut utiliser le pronom **en** pour remplacer quelque chose après **de**, par exemple :

> As-tu de l'argent ?
>
> Oui, j'**en** ai un peu. (== j'ai un peu [d'argent]).

On peut utiliser **en** pour remplacer quelque chose après une adverbe de quantité, par exemple :

> Est-ce qu'il a beaucoup d'options ?
>
> Non, il n'**en** a pas beaucoup. Il **en** a seulement deux. (== Non, il n'a pas beaucoup [d'options]. Il a seulement deux [options]).

Je pense (mais je ne suis pas sûr) que l'on peut utiliser dans le cas ci-dessous aussi :

> J'ai parlé des problèmes économiques à Jean.
>
> Oh oui ? Je lui **en** ai parlé aussi.

Ok, c'est tout que je sais.

J'ai vu ce dialogue ce matin :

> Quels sont les îles des Antilles Françaises ?
>
> La Guadeloupe et la Martinique. Il y **en** a d'autres ?

Ok, on dit **en** pour remplacer quelque chose après **de**, donc on a remplacé "Antilles Françaises", mais ça n'a pas de sens pour moi car dans ce cas la phrase serait :

> La Guadeloupe et la Martinique. Il y a d'autres Antilles Françaises ?

Dans cette question il semble qu'on a demandé si il y a d'autres Antilles Françaises (c'est à dire, si il y a quelque chose comme "Antilles Françaises II"), pas si il y a une autre île dans la région en Amérique connue sous le nom "Antilles Françaises".

Je pense que l'on doit dire :

> La Guadeloupe et la Martinique. Il y a d'**autres îles des [ou dans les]** Antilles Françaises ?

Quelqu'un peut-il faire des commentaires sur ce cas svp ?

J'ai aussi entendu cette expression ce matin :

> Très bien. On fera du lèche-vitrines pour une ou deux heures. Veux-tu que je conduise ?
>
> Il n'**en** est pas question, je ne te fais pas confiance.

Il n'y a pas de **de**, d'**adverbe de quantité** ou de **nombre** qui peuvent être remplacés par **en**, donc je soupçonne que "Il n'en est pas question" est une expression du français. Quelqu'un peut-il confirmer ça ?

---

J'ai suis sûr d'avoir entendu une fois quelqu'un qui disait "J'en sais" — et je suis désolé mais j'ai oublié le contexte. Le verbe *savoir* ne demande pas *de* donc est-ce qu'il est possible d'avoir des cas où on peut utiliser *en* avec *savoir* ?

Answer (score 3):

Vous avez mentionné l'exemple :

> Quels sont les îles des Antilles Françaises ?
>
> La Guadeloupe et la Martinique. Il y en a d'autres ?

Ici, **en** ne remplace pas *Antilles Françaises* mais les *îles des Antilles Françaises* : **en** remplace le groupe nominal dans son intégralité. Donc la réponse équivaut à demander :

> La Guadeloupe et la Martinique. Il y a d'autres îles des Antilles Françaises ?

L'interlocuteur demande donc s'il existe d'autres îles que la Guadeloupe et la Martinique dans le groupe d'îles appelé Antilles Françaises (donc il demande s'il n'a pas oublié d'îles, autres que celles qu'il a cité).

---

Pour votre deuxième cas :

> Très bien. On fera du lèche-vitrines pour un ou deux heures. Veux-tu
>   que je conduise ?
>
> Il n'en est pas question, je ne te fais pas confiance.

Ici, **en** remplace *que je conduise*, ce qui équivaut donc à dire :

> Il n'est pas question que tu conduises, je ne te fais pas confiance.

En d'autres termes, **je refuse que tu conduises** (Il n'est pas question que *quelque chose* est une expression qui signifie *en aucun cas*).

---

On peut utiliser **en** avec savoir dans de nombreux cas. Par exemple :

> Crois-moi, le football ce n'est plus ce que c'était, j'en sais quelque chose.

Ici, *en* remplace *le football ce n'est plus ce que c'était*, on peut donc reformuler la phrase :

> Je sais que le football n'est plus ce qu'il était.

Ou dans l'expression très utilisée :

> Je n'en sais rien *(souvent écourtée J'en sais rien)*

Par exemple :

> — Quelle est la racine carrée de 3249 ?
>
> — Je n'en sais rien

Ce qui signifie *Je ne sais pas quelle est la racine carrée de 3249* (au même titre que Je **n'en** ai aucune idée).

Comment: Ok - j'ai compris le premier cas - dans celui _en remplace le groupe nominal dans son intégralité_. Je ne savais pas que **en** remplace tout le groupe. Donc, oui, ce cas fait sens maintenant. Merci :) Je crains que je n'ai pas compris les deux autres. Dans le deuxième cas: _en remplace que je conduise_ - oui, je comprendre ce que il remplace mais je ne comprendre pas la raison pour laquelle on doit utiliser **en**. Il n'y a pas de **de** ou **adverbe de quantité** ou **numèro**. Pourquoi on ne peut pas utiliser le pronom impersonnel **le** dans ce cas ? _Il ne **l**'est pas question_ ?

Comment: J'ai la même doute pour le troisième cas : pourquoi on ne peut pas dire _je **le** sais_ ?

Comment: Ici, *que je conduise* est une proposition subordonnée conjonctive complétive qui a pour fonction COD. Imaginons que la personne réponde *Je ne veux pas que tu conduise*, dans ce cas, on peut dire *Je ne veux pas cela* donc *Je ne le veux pas*. Cependant l'expression qui suit est **être question de quelque chose**, on à donc *Il n'est pas question de cela* (avec **de**), on ne donc peut que dire **Il n'en est pas question**.

Comment: De même pour le 3ème cas : Si la personne dit *Je sais cela*, alors on doit le remplacer par **Je le sais**. En revanche si il dit *Je sais quelque chose de cela* alors on doit le remplacer par **J'en sais quelque chose** (car on a de).